# How can i do daily gift screen on LibGDX

Tags: java, libgdx

I want to make an offline daily gift system. How can I do it.

```
date = new Date();
        calendarG = new GregorianCalendar();
        calendarG.setTime(date);
   if(!prefs.contains("lastloginday"))
            prefs.putInteger("lastloginday", calendarG.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));

        if (calendarG.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) - 1 == prefs.getInteger("lastloginday")) {
            prefs.putInteger("lastloginday", calendarG.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
            prefs.putInteger("dailyCombo", prefs.getInteger("dailyCombo") + 1);
            prefs.putInteger("Coin", prefs.getInteger("Coin") + prefs.getInteger("dailyCombo") * 25);
        }else{
            prefs.putInteger("lastloginday", calendarG.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
        }
```

This code is not useful in different months.

Comment: What if somebody gets hold of preferences?

Comment: @Sneh Unfortunately, the game is hacked when the time settings change. What can be done if the game is offline ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do in this way :

```
Preferences preferences=Gdx.app.getPreferences("MyPref");
String LAST_LOGIN_DAY="lastloginday";    

GregorianCalendar calendarG = new GregorianCalendar();
calendarG.setTime(new Date());


if(!preferences.contains(LAST_LOGIN_DAY)) {
    //first day in App
    preferences.putInteger(LAST_LOGIN_DAY, calendarG.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR));
    preferences.flush();
}

if(preferences.getInteger(LAST_LOGIN_DAY)-1==calendarG.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR)){
    //next loginday up to a year

    updateValue(preferences,calendarG);

}else{

      if(calendarG.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR)==1) {

            // check for the 1st day of the year

            boolean isLeap = calendarG.isLeapYear(calendarG.get(Calendar.YEAR));
            if (isLeap && preferences.getInteger(LAST_LOGIN_DAY)==366 ) {

               updateValue(preferences,calendarG);

            }else  if(preferences.getInteger(LAST_LOGIN_DAY)==365){
                updateValue(preferences,calendarG);

            }
            else
                preferences.putInteger(LAST_LOGIN_DAY,calendarG.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR));
        }
        else
            preferences.putInteger(LAST_LOGIN_DAY,calendarG.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR));

}
```

Here is update method :

```
public void updateValue(Preferences preferences,GregorianCalendar calendarG){

    preferences.putInteger(LAST_LOGIN_DAY,calendarG.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR));
    preferences.putInteger("dailyCombo", preferences.getInteger("dailyCombo",0) + 1);
    preferences.putInteger("Coin", preferences.getInteger("Coin",0) + preferences.getInteger("dailyCombo",0) * 25);

    preferences.flush();
}
```